# Oracle plsql error PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

I Am writing and pl/sql procedure and getting the error as
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements and
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values

first i called a cursor and iterate the cursor and again fetching into a record there error is coming.

```
declare 
  type t1 is record (
    msisdn varchar2(20),
    imsi varchar2(14),
    date_time date,
    mml_cmd varchar2(50),
    cmd_executed varchar2(2500),
    myrank number);
    type t2 is table of t1;
    l_k t2;
    type t3 is table of hlr_agent_logs%rowtype;
    l_tab t3;
     cursor c1 is select * from hlr_agent_logs where date_time>trunc(sysdate-2) and mml_cmd='ADD USER' and cmd_executed like '%Profile=3%' order by date_time;
    
begin
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 bulk collect into l_tab limit 500;
    exit when l_tab.count=0;
    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
    
               begin
               select msisdn, imsi, date_time , mml_cmd,cmd_executed,rank() over (partition by imsi order by date_time asc)  as myrank into l_k from hlr_agent_logs 
                  where substr(msisdn,3)=l_tab(i).msisdn and imsi=l_tab(i).imsi and date_time>=l_tab(i).date_time;
                 for k  in l_k.first..l_k.last loop 
                   dbms_output.put_line(l_k(k).msisdn);
                 end loop;
                 
                 exception when no_data_found then 
                   null;
                 end;
        end loop;
    close c1;
   end loop;
 end;
 /
```

Comment: can you provide the structure of the table hlr_agent_logs ??

Answer (score 3):

What you can and can't do with PLSQL collections directly from SQL varies from version to version, but it might be as simply as you not having the BULK COLLECT because you are fetching into a table

```
SQL> declare
  2    type rec is record (
  3       c1 int,
  4       c2 int );
  5
  6    type mylist is table of rec;
  7    n mylist;
  8  begin
  9      select 1,2 into n from dual;
 10  end;
 11  /
    select 1,2 into n from dual;
                    *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 21:
PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements
ORA-06550: line 9, column 23:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    type rec is record (
  3       c1 int,
  4       c2 int );
  5
  6    type mylist is table of rec;
  7    n mylist;
  8  begin
  9      select 1,2 bulk collect into n from dual;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Connor McDonnal wisely said, depending on the version, you can or cannot use PLSQL types on SQL, but having them declared as schema objects. As you did not say which version of Oracle are you using, let me show you an example with Oracle 19c

```
declare 
  type t1 is record (
    msisdn varchar2(20),
    imsi varchar2(14),
    date_time date,
    mml_cmd varchar2(50),
    cmd_executed varchar2(2500),
    myrank number);
    type t2 is table of t1;
    l_k t2;
    type t3 is table of hlr_agent_logs%rowtype;
    l_tab t3;
     cursor c1 is select * from hlr_agent_logs where date_time>trunc(sysdate-2) and mml_cmd='ADD USER' and cmd_executed like '%Profile=3%' order by date_time;
 begin
  open c1;
  loop
    fetch c1 bulk collect into l_tab limit 500;
    exit when l_tab.count=0;
    for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
              begin
               select msisdn, imsi, date_time , mml_cmd,cmd_executed,rank() over (partition by imsi order by date_time asc)  as myrank bulk collect into l_k 
               from hlr_agent_logs 
               where substr(msisdn,3)=l_tab(i).msisdn and imsi=l_tab(i).imsi and date_time>=l_tab(i).date_time;
                 for k  in l_k.first..l_k.last loop 
                   dbms_output.put_line(l_k(k).msisdn);
                 end loop;
                 exception when no_data_found then 
                   null;
                 end;
        end loop;
    close c1;
   end loop;
 end;
 /
```

Output

```
SQL> l
  1  declare
  2    type t1 is record (
  3      msisdn varchar2(20),
  4      imsi varchar2(14),
  5      date_time date,
  6      mml_cmd varchar2(50),
  7      cmd_executed varchar2(2500),
  8      myrank number);
  9      type t2 is table of t1;
 10      l_k t2;
 11      type t3 is table of hlr_agent_logs%rowtype;
 12      l_tab t3;
 13       cursor c1 is select * from hlr_agent_logs where date_time>trunc(sysdate-2) and mml_cmd='ADD USER' and cmd_executed like '%Profile=3%' order by date_time;
 14   begin
 15    open c1;
 16    loop
 17      fetch c1 bulk collect into l_tab limit 500;
 18      exit when l_tab.count=0;
 19      for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last loop
 20                begin
 21                 select msisdn, imsi, date_time , mml_cmd,cmd_executed,rank() over (partition by imsi order by date_time asc)  as myrank bulk collect into l_k
 22                        from hlr_agent_logs
 23                 where substr(msisdn,3)=l_tab(i).msisdn and imsi=l_tab(i).imsi and date_time>=l_tab(i).date_time;
 24                   for k  in l_k.first..l_k.last loop
 25                     dbms_output.put_line(l_k(k).msisdn);
 26                   end loop;
 27                   exception when no_data_found then
 28                     null;
 29                   end;
 30          end loop;
 31      close c1;
 32     end loop;
 33*  end;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```